# Redirect "302 found" vs "302 object moved"

Tags: seo, redirects

Examining several different websites that do redirects (from TLD to language subfolders), I discovered that beside sending a 302 HTTP header, some send differents strings:

Some send `"302 found"`, others send `"302 object moved"`.

**Regarding SEO, my question is:**

Does the string description matter to Google and Bing, or are they simply evaluating the HTTP header numbers (301, 302, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The number (302) tells them what they need to know. The words are just to make humans happy. If someone uses the wrong words it's no big deal. But if you use the wrong number it will affect how user agents handle them.